# website snippet missing in google search engine

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, web, seo

First of all I'm very new in seo. Currently, I'm developing a website. my problem is about the missing site snippet.

When im trying to search the site using Google's search engine it gives a result like this:

> www.xxxxxxxx.com.ph/
>   A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt – learn more.

but on my header tags on each pages i have code like this:

> ```
>   <title> PH SAMPLE XXXXX | Official site</title>
>     <link rel="shortcut icon" href="_img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
>     <meta name="description" content="Each Antica Murrina jewellery is the result of a combination of traditional craftsmanship and style-conscious minded fashion and trends." />
>     <meta name="keywords" content="Antica Murrina, Glam Glass 2012, Fashion Glass Jewellery, accessory, Venezia, handmade, design" />
> ```

What did I missed to meet the exact format as my header tag?
Please help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is nothing wrong with the meta tags inside the head of your page.

The problem lies on the server where you should find a file called `robots.txt` that tells Google's crawler to not crawl your website. This will negatively affect your site's SEO as Google will probably not even no that there exist other pages within your website.

You could just delete the file on your server or just delete the entry that prevents Google from crawling your website.

If you want your website to be indexed by all search engine to increase SEO just delete the file completely.

EDIT: Here is a link if you want to read more about `robots.txt`
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'm afraid to say that I can't find any robots.txt file on the directory..

Comment: It is usually in the root directory `In order to use a robots.txt file, you'll need to have access to the root of your domain (if you're not sure, check with your web hoster). If you don't have access to the root of a domain, you can restrict access using the robots meta tag.`

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in your comments to @J2D8T you do not have a robots.txt file on your site. By navigating to

http://anticamurrina.com.ph/robots.txt

We can confirm this is the case, therefore there should be no reason you are recieving this message. It does not appear that you are using any CMS and therefore there should be no block. According to this article

http://www.seroundtable.com/google-robots-snippet-15576.html

A few people have had success by simply creating a robots.txt as sometimes the absence of one can cause an issue (however this may be Wordpress specific). I would suggest you manually create a robots.txt file.

Simply create the file robots.txt and place the following inside (this enables access to everything)

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Then  you will need to upload this to the root of your website (same place as tyhe index), on success you should be able to navigate to

http://anticamurrina.com.ph/robots.txt

and see the file present.

I have tested the site with Lynx text browser and the site is appearing as expected.

http://www.vordweb.co.uk/standards/download_lynx.htm

I would suggest after creating the robots.txt file, simply wait a few days and then check google again to see if the description is being pulled in correctly.

Comment: Hi. I followed this and will observe for next few days.. I will let you know the result soon. Thank you very much!

Comment: http://anticamurrina.com.ph/robots.txt is still throwing a 404 error. Please double check the file is definitely a .txt extension and it is is the root of the webserver, in the same place as the index file for your site.

Comment: Hi. 

This is resolved. I didnt used a robots.txt that why its still 404. I considered what you said since that I'm not using any CMS so why the site is "kinda" blocked the content.

Sometimes waiting is the key. Btw, thanks for the assistance. I will used those as future reference. 

Cheers!

Comment: @cyx Not a problem glad you got it sorted.